# How to translate "Permanent link to" text

Tags: permalinks

My theme contains the following to create permalinks:

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

However I want to translate the "Permanent link to" text.

How do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: the_title_attribute function should not prepend the text "Permant link to", your theme possibly using the_title hook to add the string. Look on your theme where it says `add_filter('the_title', '');` and if they have used gettext then you can translate it. Otherwise you will need to edit it on the theme file.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot find an add_filter command in the theme's files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible way:

```
<?php
$link_text = sprintf( 
                 __( 'Permanent link to %s', 'youthemetextdomain'),
                 get_the_title() ); ?>

<h3><a
    href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'
    title='<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>'
><?php echo $link_text; ?></a></h3>
```

get_the_title() returns the title instead of displaying it. The double-underscore function is how WordPress allows strings to be extracted from a theme or plugin for translation.